# Getting recommendations letters after the referee has left the institution?

Tags: masters, recommendation-letter, germany

I am applying for admissions into Master's programs in Germany. Many programs here prefer printed/scanned letters on institutional letter-headed paper.

One of the professors with whom I was well acquainted with during my undergraduate studies joined another university. Moreover, a very senior manager at my workplace, with whom I have worked on a lot of stuff and also have a good rapport, is to retire soon.

Please give advice as to how effective recommendation letters can be obtained from referees whose association with the institution/organization that linked them to the recommended applicant has ended.

Comment: You say "prefer" letters on institutional letterhead - do you know how much of an issue it would be if it was not on letterhead, but explained the circumstances? (Or is that something you'd like to get feedback on?) For the professor that moved, would there be an issue with providing a recommendation letter on their new institution's letterhead? For the professor who retired, did they do so on "emeritus" status, which may still have access to institutional letterhead?

Comment: @R.M. The issue of letterhead needs to be discussed with universities individually for more detail (even if they mention it on their website). Moreover, the soon to retire person is not a professor (or affiliated with a university), although he has a doctorate.

Comment: I would ask the programs you are applying to if there is any issue(most likely the institutions don't care much about it), but I would expect the professor at another institution would write a letter on their current letterhead, and in the letter would simply state "When I was an Associate Professor of Academia at Grand Old University..." for clarity; the retiring manager is to retire *soon* so if they can write a letter before they do so then I see no problem, though unfortunately companies have various policies on letters of recommendation that can be restrictive, so be aware of those first.

Comment: @BryanKrause Your suggestion about the professor is helpful and I agree with it. As for the manager, I would not bother him at a time when he is literally packing up to leave the country. I will get his consent now and only get the letter when it can be most useful.